# Why does one of the lines in my ERG model show NA?

Tags: r, statnet

I'm building an ERGM on statnet and one of the lines shows NA, which I don't know how to interpret. All of the other nodefactors show results but this one just shows:

```
nodefactor.religion.1                 NA     0.0000      0      NA       NA
```

The column it's pulling from is just a bunch of 1s and 0s, so I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: hard to tell without more details. could be due to collinearity. could you provide more details about your network, the full ERGM output, and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @paqmo thanks!
The network has 206 vertices and about 600 edges. The vertex attributes are pulled from a meta, and the ERGM gives results for all of the attributes except "religion". 

                                Estimate Std. Error MCMC % z value Pr(>|z|)    
edges                            -5.8087     0.3743      0 -15.518   <1e-04 ***

nodefactor.caste.SCHEDULE TRIBE   0.5634     0.1114      0   5.059   <1e-04 ***
nodefactor.religion.1                 NA     0.0000      0      NA       NA

Comment: yeah, hard to tell without seeing the data. Can you share it, or a subset of it, using `dput()` in your question? You could try examining the mixing matrix for religion to see if you spot something unusual--`mixingmatrix(network, "religion")`